# MATLAB can't seem to find csaps() in MATLAB 7.10.0 student edition

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have some code using `csaps()`, Matlab's [cubic smoothing spline fitting function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/curvefit/csaps.html) that I want to give to a student with MATLAB 7.10.0 (R2010a).

For some reason the function doesn't seem to exist, even though the student has the Curve Fitting Toolbox installed:

```
EDU>> ver
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB Version 7.10.0.499 (R2010a)
MATLAB License Number: STUDENT
Operating System: Microsoft Windows XP Version 5.1 (Build 2600: Service Pack 3)
Java VM Version: Java 1.6.0_12-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM mixed mode
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB                                                Version 7.10       (R2010a)
Simulink                                              Version 7.5        (R2010a)
Control System Toolbox                                Version 8.5        (R2010a)
Curve Fitting Toolbox                                 Version 2.2        (R2010a)
Image Processing Toolbox                              Version 7.0        (R2010a)
Optimization Toolbox                                  Version 5.0        (R2010a)
Signal Processing Blockset                            Version 7.0        (R2010a)
Signal Processing Toolbox                             Version 6.13       (R2010a)
Statistics Toolbox                                    Version 7.3        (R2010a)
Symbolic Math Toolbox                                 Version 5.4        (R2010a)
EDU>> csaps
??? Undefined function or variable 'csaps'.
```

Am I missing something here?
Here is the output of `path`.

```
EDU>> path

        MATLABPATH

    C:\Documents and Settings\alkemagroup\My Documents\MATLAB
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\general
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\ops
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\lang
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\elmat
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\randfun
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\elfun
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\specfun
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\matfun
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\datafun
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\polyfun
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\funfun
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\sparfun
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\scribe
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\graph2d
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\graph3d
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\specgraph
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\graphics
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\uitools
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\strfun
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\imagesci
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\iofun
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\audiovideo
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\timefun
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\datatypes
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\verctrl
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\codetools
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\helptools
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\winfun
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\winfun\NET
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\demos
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\timeseries
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\hds
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\guide
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\plottools
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\local
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\dastudio
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\matlab\datamanager
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\simulink
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\instrument
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\simulink\simulink
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\simulink\simulink\slresolve
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\simulink\blocks
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\simulink\components
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\simulink\fixedandfloat
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\simulink\fixedandfloat\fxpdemos
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\simulink\fixedandfloat\obsolete
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\simulink\simdemos
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\simulink\simdemos\aerospace
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\simulink\simdemos\automotive
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\simulink\simdemos\industrial
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\simulink\simdemos\simfeatures
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\simulink\simdemos\simgeneral
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\simulink\dee
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\dastudio\depviewer
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\stateflow\stateflow
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\rtw\rtw
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\sigbldr
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\simulink\simulink\MPlayIO
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\simulink\simulink\dataobjectwizard
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\hdlshared
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\rtw\accel
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\rtw\targets\shared
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\simulink\simulink\modeladvisor
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\simulink\simulink\modeladvisor\fixpt
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\stateflow\sfdemos
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\stateflow\coder
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\rtw\targets\AUTOSAR\AUTOSAR
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\control\control
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\control\ctrlguis
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\control\ctrlobsolete
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\control\ctrlutil
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\control\ctrldemos
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\slcontrollib
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\options
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\controllib\general
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\controllib\graphics
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\controllib\requirements
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\curvefit\curvefit
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\curvefit\cftoolgui
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\curvefit\sftoolgui
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\optimlib
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\dspblks\dspblks
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\dspblks\dspmasks
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\dspblks\dspmex
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\dspblks\dspdemos
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\filterdesignlib
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\dspblks\splibmex
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\system
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\dspblks\dspblks
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\dspblks\dspmex
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\fixedpoint\fixedpoint
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\help\toolbox\dspblks\examples
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\eml\eml
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\emlcoder\emlcoder
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\emlcoder\emlcodermex
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\simtargets
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\fixedpoint\fixedpointtool
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\spcuilib
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\siglib
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\images\colorspaces
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\images\images
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\images\imdemos
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\images\imuitools
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\images\iptformats
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\images\iptutils
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\imageslib
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\slvnv\simcoverage
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\optim\optim
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\optim\optimdemos
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\rptgen
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\signal\signal
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\signal\sigtools
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\signal\sptoolgui
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\signal\sigdemos
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\sl3d\sl3d
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\sl3d\sl3ddemos
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\sldv
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\stats
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\shared\statslib
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\symbolic\symbolicdemos
EDU>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Release 2010b [merged](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/curvefit/rn/bslyu07-1.html) the Spline toolbox into the Curve Fitting Toolbox. Users with a license for the Spline Toolbox and an active service contract were given a license for the Curve Fitting Toolbox to replace the discontinued Spline Toolbox when they upgraded to R2010b.

`csaps` was a function of the Spline Toolbox in R2010a. Thus, it is not available in the set of toolboxes your student has. Try and see whether your student can swap the Curve Fitting Toolbox for the Spline Toolbox, or upgrade to R2010b.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following directory is missing from your path:

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a Student\toolbox\curvefit\splines
```

That is the directory where [CSAPS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/curvefit/csaps.html) appears in the full version of R2010b.  <strike>I'm not sure if it just isn't included in the student version, or if it was somehow removed in your `pathdef.m` file.</strike> *As noted in [Jonas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797794/matlab-cant-seem-to-find-csaps-in-matlab-7-10-0-student-edition/4797939#4797939), that folder isn't there in R2010a (it was still a part of the Spline toolbox).*

Comment: Weird. The splines directory just doesn't exist. Why would the Student Version only include part of the curve fitting toolbox? This is a virgin installation.