# Matlab Path issue: can't find spline functions although Curve Fitting Toolbox is installed

Tags: path, matlab, curve-fitting

Here is the output of my paths:

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app/toolbox/curvefit/curvefit
/Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app/toolbox/curvefit/cftoolgui
/Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app/toolbox/curvefit/sftoolgui
```

When I run anything using

```
spap2
csapi
```

I get

> ??? Undefined function or method 'csapi' for input arguments of type
>   'double'.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797794/matlab-cant-seem-to-find-csaps-in-matlab-7-10-0-student-edition) seems to address a similar issue but it's not re my version, which is R2009b.

Comment: `csapi` is in `/toolbox/curvefit/spline` in my Matlab installation. Try running `which csapi` to confirm that it doesn't exist on your path.

Comment: if you have a broken path, you could try to reset it to its default state with `restoredefaultpath` (warning: this will remove any user-defined ones)

Comment: Similar to what Jonas said, but make sure that you don't have a local function called `csapi` which would shadow Matlab's built-in function

Comment: Matlab also outputs this when calling a function you do not have a license for. Try `license('test', 'Curve_Fitting_Toolbox')` to see if you have the license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for your input. At the end, this was resolved by running an upgrade to 7.13 (2011b). I believe this may be an issue similar to the post I linked in the OP.

It appears that spline plotting functions (former Spline Toolbox, deprecated) are now all in the Curve Fitting Toolbox. So if you have earlier versions of Matlab (< 2010), it will search for those functions in the wrong place (Spline Toolbox) even if you have the Curve Fitting Toolbox. I presume those functions would only work on an older Matlab install if you happen to have the Spline Toolbox installed as well.

Again, the solution here is to upgrade both your Matlab install and your Curve Fitting Toolbox. Then you'll have access to the functions I mentioned above.